# case when clause in sql query in db2

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a db2/AS400 database and I'm trying to do the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id IN (
    CASE 
     WHEN 1=1 THEN
        (SELECT id
        FROM user AS userInner
        WHERE userInner.salary < 10)
     ELSE
        (SELECT id
        FROM user AS userInner
        WHERE userInner.salary > 20)
    END
)
```

The 1=1 condition depends on something else, but it's ok for this simple example. However what I get as an error is the following:

> SQL Error [21000]: [SQL0811] Result of SELECT more than one row.

How it would be possible to use case when or other way in order to have a sql_statement condition with multiple results?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `CASE`.
You can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM user
  WHERE (1=1 AND userInner.salary < 10)
     OR (1<>1 AND userInner.salary > 20)
)
```

Of course you have to replace `1=1` with your actual condition and `1<>1` with its reverse.